# what is the definition of pure strategy of zero sum games?

Tags: game-theory

what is the definition of pure strategy of zero sum games?

I tried to google for results, but no clear definition came up .

EDIT:
I found a definition in a game theory book . told me exactly what I needed to know
"A mixed strategy in which a particular move is played with probability one is known as a pure strategy"
.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_%28game_theory%29#Pure_and_mixed_strategies) is your friend.

Comment: the zero sum games Wikipedia page didn't offer a explanation.  and the strategy page on Wikipedia says that a pure strategy is the strategy set. So i'm still confused at what a pure strategy is and how to find pure strategies for zero sum games.

Comment: In a situation, you may have a choice among several options. If, in that situation, you always take the same option, you are playing a pure strategy; if in a given situation you don't always take the same option, you are playing a mixed strategy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so the difference lies in whether or not the behaviour of a person following the strategy is deterministic?

Comment: For some games, the best strategy is a probabilistic one: x% of the time do X; y% of the time do Y; etc..

Comment: The strategy page on Wikipedia does **not** say that a pure strategy is the strategy set; it says that the strategy set is the set of all pure strategies. In stone-paper-scissors, the strategy set has three elements. One of the three pure strategies is "always play stone". There are an infinite number of mixed (i.e. randomized) strategies; one of them is "play stone 50% of the time, paper 30%, scissors 20%".

Comment: Actually, pure strategies are the degenerate probability distributions, hence can be viewed as mixed strategies too.